# Удаление данных из БД, не отмеченных чекбоксом

Tags: php, mysql

Добавить данные в БД, отмеченные чекбоксом просто. А вот удалить, не отмеченные что-то не получается.
Вот так выглядит обработка добавления:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['level']); $i++)
{
$reg = mysql_query("select * from `users_access` where `razdel`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['level'][$i])."' AND `id_user`='".$row['id']."'");
if (mysql_num_rows($reg) == 0)
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users_access` SET `id_user`='".$row['id']."', `razdel` = '".$_POST['level'][$i]."'");
}
```

И сами чекбоксы:

```
$dir = opendir('./');
while ($razdel = readdir($dir)) {
if (($razdel != '.') && ($razdel != '..')) {
$reg = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select * from `users_access` where `razdel`='".mysql_real_escape_string($razdel)."' AND `id_user`='".$row['id']."'"));
echo '<label><input class="example_check" type="checkbox" name="level[]" value="'.$razdel.'" '.($reg['razdel'] == $razdel ? 'checked="checked"' : '').'>'.$razdel.'</label><br/>';
}
}
closedir($dir);
```

Comment: Браузер не отправляет с формой неотмеченные поля типа чекбокс. Вам нужно на стороне сервера сравнивать текущее значение записи из БД (из которого вы форму формируете) с пришедшими значениями (покурите array_diff_key). Результат сохраняйте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="all[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="2"><input type="hidden" name="all[]" value="2"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="3"><input type="hidden" name="all[]" value="3">

 ....
<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="n"><input type="hidden" name="all[]" value="n">
```

На сервере получаешь массивы id[] и all[]. Получаешь третий массив delete[] из разницы массивов id[] И all[]

```
$delete_unselected=implode(",",$delete);
```

отправляешь запрос в базу на удаление:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `table` WHERE IN($delete_unselected)");
```

Comment: Возможно можно и так. Но более простой вариант я написал выше.

Comment: @vitagame, а если в форме не весь список из базы? Да и чем меньше запросов, тем лучше.

Comment: Ну в моем случае все работает прекрасно так, как я написал.

Answer (score 0):

Жесть!

[@Ёхарный Бабай](/users/2636/%D1%91%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9) ты реально делал бы так как написал? Это жесть!

Такие штуки делаете. Не проще взять JS или с использованием Jquery при нажатии на кнопку "удалить" получить отмеченные чекбоксы и ajax запросом отправить их значения?! Быстрее сработает.

Коммент [@DreamChild](/users/10162/dreamchild) плюсую!

Comment: я бы сделал именно так, еслиб у меня был уровень ТС.

Кстати, как сервер будет знать что из чего удалять? Допустим, в базе N записей. На сайт я загружаю m (m<n намного) записей с чекбоксами. И мне надо удалить из m записей те, что не отмечены. Естественно, без аякса.

Comment: Соглашусь про уровень ТС.

Но при поставленном вопросе ТС - это вообще бредовая идея. Я даже не поинмаю как можно поставить себе такую дурную задачу.

Answer (score -1):

А решил проблему так:
удаляю из бд все значения для определенного пользователя

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `users_access` WHERE `id_user` = '".$row['id']."'");
```

после в цикле пишу в бд значения, отмеченные чекбоксом.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['level']); $i++)
{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users_access` SET `id_user`='".$row['id']."', `razdel` = '".$_POST['level'][$i]."'");
}
mysql_query("OPTIMIZE TABLE `users_access`");
```

Comment: @vitagame, я не поставлю минус, только потому, что искренне вам сочувствую.

Comment: Так толсто, что даже тонко.